# Is the polynomial $6x^4+3x^3+6x^2+2x+5\in GF(7)[x]$ irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $6x^4+3x^3+6x^2+2x+5\in GF(7)[x]$ irreducible?

What is the best/simplest/elementary way to approach this? Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it _is_ reducible, then it either has a root, or has a monic quadratic factor. That makes brute force look feasible: there are only 49 quadratics in the first place, and 28 of those split into linear factors (and can therefore be ignored), so there's only 21 test divisions to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. If we set $p(x)=6x^4+3x^3+6x^2+2x+5$, over $\mathbb{F}_7$ we have:
$$ p(x+2) = -\left(x^4-2x^3-2x+1\right) $$
that is a palyndromic polynomial, from which:
$$\frac{p(x+2)}{x^2} = -\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) = -\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2$$
and:
$$ p(x+2) = -(x^2+2x+3)(x^2+3x-2),$$
since the previous line gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} p(x+2)=-(x^2+1)^2+2x(x^2+1)+2x^2&=&-(x^2+1-x)^2+3x^2\\&=&-(x^2+1-4x)^2+2(x+2)^2\end{eqnarray*} $$
and the RHS is now the difference of two squares.

A viable alternative is to notice, through Stickelberger criterion, that since the discriminant of $p$, $\Delta=-1728=-12^3$, is a quadratic residue $\pmod{7}$, $p$ splits as the product of an *even* number of irreducible polynomials, hence $p$ cannot be irreducible.

Comment: How do you get from the penultimate equation to the last?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I split both $x^2+1$ and $x^2-2x-2$ over $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$ and re-combined the results.

Comment: How did you know to look at $p(x+2)$?  Tried each $p(x+k)$ hoping to get lucky?

Comment: @MJD: exactly so :D

Comment: Still completely opaque to me what happens there. Could you edit in some more details about what it is you're doing?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: for short, that palyndromic-polynomial thing gives that the Galois group of $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, hence $p(x)$ cannot be irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$. Better now?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: No, I'm not looking for "for short", but for something long enough for me to understand what is going on. Where does the last line of your answer come from? It looks like you're pulling that factorization out of thin air. How did the part that came before it help you find it? Does it have anything to do with the next-to-last line? Please add some intermediate steps and a description of how the next-to-last line relates to the last one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: all right, done.

Comment: My confusion is monotonically increasing. You have have now offered three explanations of how you get to that last factorization, which seem to me to have nothing to do with each other -- the first two ones I don't understand at all, and the one you've now edited into the answer appears to consist of pulling some random algebraic coincidences out of thin air. Does that have anything to do with "splitting over $\mathbb F_{7^2}$" and/or "Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$", and if so what? And how do either of them relate to starting with a palindrome?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for your response. However, this approach is way over my head. Do you know of any more elementary approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Because the modulus is so small, we can do this the hard way.

All arithmetic will be done in $\mathbb Z_7.$

$p(x)=6x^4+3x^3+6x^2+2x+5$

$-p(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 + x^2 + 5x + 2$

$-p(x-1) = x^4 + 2x^2 + 4x + 2$

Now we suppose that
\begin{align}
   -p(x-1)
      &= (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)\\
      &= x^4 + (a+c)x^3 + (ac + b + d)x^2 + (ad + bc)x + bd
\end{align}

We end up with the equations
\begin{align}
   a+c &= 0\\
   ac + b + d &= 2\\
   ad+bc &= 4\\
   bd &= 2
\end{align}

Iterating through $b$, we finally get $(a,b,c,d) = (4,1,3,2)$.

So 
\begin{align}
   -p(x-1) &= (x^2 + 4x + 1)(x^2 + 3x + 2)\\
    p(x-1) &= -(x^2 + 4x + 1)(x^2 + 3x + 2)\\
      p(x) &= -(x^2 + 5x + 3)(x^2 + 6x + 3)\\
\end{align}